# ADF: API With Nested JSON Arrays to Flat File

Tags: arrays, azure-data-factory

In ADF I am calling an API source that's returning nested/complex JSON that I need to flatten out into csv files.

The Copy Activity wont work for me. It will only read the first record from the nested data.

I need to be able to call and then flatten the aliases array

Here is an example of the response from the API:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "title_no": 12345,
        "booking_xref_title_no": 45305,
        "edi_no": "2495",
        "title_global_id": "TTL-11",
        "aliases": [
            {
                "source_name": "123A",
                "title_alias_global_id": "ABC1234"
            },
            {
                "source_name": "123B",
                "title_alias_global_id": "ABC5678"
```

I need to get the following into my output csv:

| source_name | title_global_id |
| --- | --- |
| 123A | ABC1234 |
| 123B | ABC5678 |

Answer (score 0):

Json output given in question is incomplete. So I added few braces to it.

JSON response should be as given below:

```
{
   "items":[
      {
         "title_no":12345,
         "booking_xref_title_no":45305,
         "edi_no":"2495",
         "title_global_id":"TTL-11",
         "aliases":[
            {
               "source_name":"123A",
               "title_alias_global_id":"ABC1234"
            },
            {
               "source_name":"123B",
               "title_alias_global_id":"ABC5678"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

With above JSON response, you can flatten it and save output to CSV file as shown in below steps.

Use JSON response as Source to **DataFlow Activity** in Azure data factory.

[image]

Select document form as Single document.

[image]

Now select Flatten transformation. Select `Unroll by = items.aliases` and do the mapping as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Data preview after Flatten transformation.

[image]

Now add CSV file as Sink.

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, however the issue is getting all the nested values from the API into a JSON file. Currently I can only get the 123A record, all subsequent records in "aliases" are ignored.

Comment: Make sure Sampling is Disable in Source settings.

Comment: If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.